# Создать массив количеств дочерних элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, css-selectors

```
<div class="step1">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

На странице имеется несколько похожих элементов, имена классов step1, step2 ... Надо создать массив из элементов, каждый из которых отображает количество дочерних (в данном случае чекбоксов.)

```
stepAnswers[1] = $('.step1 input').length;
```

Вот так получается записать количество, а через массив собрать не получается

```
for (let i in stepAnswers) {
        stepAnswers[i] = $('.step'+[i]+' input').length;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/8fbLn4o3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const result = [...document.querySelectorAll('body > div')]
  .filter(el => /(^|\s)step\d+(\s|$)/i.test(el.className)) 
  .map(el => el.children.length); 
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div class="step1">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="notstep">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="foo step2">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

1. Берем в массив все `div` верхнего уровня
2. Фильтруем его по классам, регуляркой `/(^|\s)step\d+(\s|$)/i` (отсеяв все элементы не имеющие класса `stepN`)
3. Преобразуем массив оставшихся элементов в массив количеств их дочерних (просто взяв значение свойства `children.length`)